# NodeJs String.inculdes() does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, filter

for some reason I can't filter my list properly because the `name.includes(line)` is always `false`.

```js
http
  .createServer((req, res) => {
    // .. Here you can create your data response in a JSON format
    let body = [];
    req
      .on('error', (err) => {
        console.error(err);
      })
      .on('data', (chunk) => {
        body.push(chunk);
      })
      .on('end', () => {
        body = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
        console.log(req);
        const list = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)).filter(({ name }) => {
          console.log(
            name.toLowerCase(),
            body.toLowerCase(),
            name.toLowerCase().includes(body.toLowerCase())
          );
          console.log(name.toLowerCase().includes('damage'));
          return name.toLowerCase().includes(body.toLowerCase());
        });
        console.log(list);
        handleResponse(req, res, data);
      });
  })
  .listen(port);
```

result:

```js
"damage"
damage reverse oil conditioner "damage" false
true
volume advance conditioner "damage" false
false
volume advance shampoo "damage" false
false
damage reverse oil shampoo "damage" false
true
color sustain pro "damage" false
false
damage reverse hair serum "damage" false
true
damage reverse restorative hair treatment "damage" false
true

[]
```

I have no clue why it shows me `false`. To check my sanity I checked the first line in the browser and in shows `true`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's [case sensitive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes#Case-sensitivity). Also why are there quotation marks around your `"damage"`?

Comment: but this not work even like that `name.toLowerCase().includes(body)`

Comment: As you already noticed, `"Damage Reverse Oil Conditioner".toLowerCase().includes("damage") === true`. Some of your strings are not what you think they are (e.g. note the quotation marks mentioned above), not strings at all (it's not `String.prototype.includes` which you are calling, or passing something that's not a string, and may mutate), or you missed `toLowerCase` before.

Comment: Can you include what `data` actually is and its type?

Comment: I might found the cause, my body for some reason cant match `body = Buffer.concat(body).toString();` but `name.toLowerCase().includes('damage')` works properly. It comes from response on the NodeJS server

Comment: here is the console log `damage reverse oil conditioner "damage" false
true
` where the second boolean is raw string

Comment: It's possible that what you have is a buffer which is not a string. A buffer is raw byte-oriented data and can be a 32 bit integer, a 32 bit floating point number, a 64 bit floating point number, a JPG image, a PDF document, a UTF-8 string, a TCP/IP packet etc. If you expect the API you are calling to return a string then you can convert the buffer to string using `body.toString()` or `body.toString('utf8')` if you expect it to be UTF-8 and contain non-english characters or emojis

Answer (score 0):

String.prototype.includes() is **case sensitive** as [listed here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes#Case-sensitivity).

Comment: but this not work even like that `name.toLowerCase().includes(body)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is my work round to fix the issue. The problem because the body converts not properly by `Buffer.concat(body).toString()`, so I changed it in this way:

```js
const bodyLine = JSON.stringify(body);
body = bodyLine.substring(3, bodyLine.length - 3);
```

and changed body creating itself:
instead of

```js
let body = [];
    req
      .on('error', (err) => {
        console.error(err);
      })
      .on('data', (chunk) => {
        body.push(chunk);
      })
```

I make replaced array with string and concatanate the chunks

```js
let body = '';
    req
      .on('error', (err) => {
        console.error(err);
      })
      .on('data', (chunk) => {
        body += chunk.toString();
      })
```